# How do i export/import MX Google Map entries

Tags: datagrab, mx-google-map

I need to transfer aprox 700 MX googlemap entries from old db to new. I have tried ajw-export/Datagrab but it does not transfer the geodata.

Comment: i would probably just merge the data in MySQL with SequelPro. e.g. setup the fields and entries and the copy over the data from the old table to the correct field_id's in channel_data

Comment: Looking for a datagrab based solution here too, I think the problem is that MX Google Map isn't DataGrab aware... or is it the other way around... :?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Google Maps for EE to do this, but you would need a .csv to do it. It comes with a geocoder/import utility that is really robust and will work for almost all data files. I know it's not for MX Google Maps, but this could save you quite a bit of time by not having to roll out a custom solution.

https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps